# Check if variable repeats and add change table column color in loop

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

I have this foreach loop getting my table values... I now want to check if the the column pid  row numbers repeats it self `$events[12]` and if so I want to add a class to the table column `<tr>` so I can replace the color of all repeating columns so they look liked group together. Here's my page : http://www.toppromomkt.com/?wallet=dezembro-2015

And the code:

```
 //now loop over data instead of mysql_fetch_array
    foreach ($data as $events) {
        echo '<table id="wallet_table1" width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">';     
        ?>

        <tr  id='<?php echo "row".$events[0] ?>' class='<?php echo $events[2] ?>' onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">  
        <?php
        echo "<td class='tb1'>{$events[0]}</td></div>";  //foto
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>{$events[7]}</td></div>";  //foto
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<div class='w_promotora_images'>{$events[3]}</td></div>";  //data
        echo "<td class=''>{$events[2]}</td>";      //nome

    echo "<td class='sle'>{$events[12]}</td>";   // this the  PID i want to check if repeats

        echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[4]}</td>";  //evento
        echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[5]}</td>";  //horario
        echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[6]}</td>";  //obs
        echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[10]}h</td>"; //horas
        echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[9]}€</td>";  //valor hora
        echo "<td class=' tb1'>{$events[1]}</td>";  //Props
        echo "<td class=' tb1'><div class='{$events[2]}'> {$events[8]}</td></div>"; //t parcial ?>
        <td class='tbrr'>  <?php 
        $strSQL1 = "SELECT nome,  SUM(totalparcial) as Soma FROM bruno_wallet  where nome='{$events[2]}' GROUP BY nome"; 
    $rs1 = mysql_query($strSQL1);
    $sum1 = 0;
    $data1 = array();
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs1)) {
       echo $row2[1]."€";
    };
    ?>
        </div> </td></tr> 



    </table>
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up the words "column" and "row".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is something like this: Store all PIDs in an array and check every time you loop through the for loop if the current PID is in the array. For example:

```
$checkedPIDs = array();
foreach ($data as $events) {
    $currentPID = $events[12];
    if (in_array($currentPID, $checkedPIDs)) {
        // Output with different colour...
    } else {
        array_push($checkedPIDs, $currentPID);
        // Output with normal colour...
    }
    // The rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: oh got it ..if (in_array($currentPID, $checkedPIDs)) u forgot to close de ) tks